# Why do some programs work when using the debugger, but not when running a normal debug execution?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, crash

I've had several times where I was writing a program using Visual Studio and something, somewhere along the line breaks.  Naturally, my first thought is to set a breakpoint early on in the program and then step through the code slowly, line by line until I reach the error.

But often times I find that everything works correctly when slowly stepping through code in the debugger. However, when I just try to run the program without breakpoints something goes wrong.

Why does this happen?  Is stepping through the code line by line actually different from just running the program in dubug mode?

*(I'm not talking about debug vs release, i'm talking about debug vs line-by-line debugging)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason could be that you have timing issues between multiple executing threads that occur differently when the program runs "at full speed" and when you pause a thread in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a some thread unsafe operations that seem to happen correctly when stepping through the code but not at run time. Compiler optimizations are ruled out because you are sure that you are running a debug build.

Answer (score 0):

Running inside the debugger materially alters the runtime options for eg. heap operations so that errors can be detected and surfaced to the user.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366705%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> When a process is run under any debugger, certain heap debug options
>   are automatically enabled for all heaps in the process.

This is not for sure your issue, but a likely candidate.

Comment: how does running under a debugger change heap behavior?

Comment: researching that, but turning off LFH is one thing it does, this can drastically alters the program's behaviour

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a local `.env` file to ingest environment variables to a python script for local testing on vscode. I was getting errors when I ran the code while the code was being executed in debug mode without errors.

The reason behind it was that by default vscode fetches environment variables from `.env` file in debug mode but not when you run the script, so you have to export environment variables for normal run by either directly exporting variables in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` files or by using `load_dotenv` using the following snippet:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

This looks for the `.env` file in the project directory and sets up the environment variables on run time.